# Using CSS/JS/jQuery Theme with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am currently writing a small static site, and I have decided to use Vue.js as I have used it in the past without major issues. This time, I have to use a pre-made template which is jQuery/Bootstrap based and most of the heavy lifting is done through JS.

I am trying to use the [Porto template](https://themeforest.net/item/porto-responsive-html5-template/4106987). I have been able to convert the basics (CSS, add the router, etc) but I am struggling with the JS side of things. From what I have been able to understand, the different "components" that come from the template are activated once the entire page has been loaded. The init script goes through the HTML DOM and "activates" them.

Usually this works fine, especially when using an old jQuery style approach, but due to Vue's lifecycle for components, the JS is not re-executed once a new component appears on the page, therefore making it look like it does not work.

The most logical approach would be to take each Porto component, and splitting it out into Vue components, with their own JS, etc. But this means that any update to the template would require a full rewrite, without forgetting the amount of work to create the first version.

Currently, I have tried wrapping the `<script>` imports in a component, and inserting it into the page. My idea was to then use the `this.$forceUpdate()` method to force a re-render, but it fails.

Any other ideas?

Comment: If your theme requires jQuery methods to be called to initialize things, you will need to investigate calling these methods in the `mounted` Vue option.  Ref. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

Comment: I agree with what you are saying, but as I have stated in the question: 

"The most logical approach would be to take each Porto component, and splitting it out into Vue components, with their own JS, etc. But this means that any update to the template would require a full rewrite, without forgetting the amount of work to create the first version."

I am trying to find a way to avoid this

Comment: Couldn’t mixins help? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Comment: Yep, mixins definitely helped...it seems to work although I have had to copy and paste the content of the file into the mixin. Is there any way to import the file and execute it? I know that ES6 imports are evaluated only once, and I need to override that behaviour